# How to do PUT request without primary key?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Like/Dislike api for a blog using DRF. I have Like table which contains "Post", "User" and "isLike" fields. Since Django can't have composite key, I'm using unique_together constraint for ("Post" and "User").

If a user likes a post, I create a entry in Like table. Now if a user wants to remove his like from the post or want to dislike the post, I need primary key of entry from Like table for these (PUT/DELETE) methods. Since I know "User" and "Post", and since both are unique, Can I perform (PUT/DELETE) methods with unique fields?

Model class

```py
class LikeDislike(models.Model):
    """model for like counts"""
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isLike = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("post", "user"),)
```

View for creating entry in Like table:

```py
class LikeDislikeCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.LikeDislike.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LikeDislikeSerializer

    def perform_create(self, LikeDislikeSerializer):
        LikeDislikeSerializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

I can update a like/dislike using -> /like/primary-key/ but I want to do using "post" and "user" details.

Comment: I've removed the sql tag, I included since problem has unique_together/primary key keywords, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just completing @AKX answer:

```
class LikeDislikeCreateUpdateDeleteView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): # generics class changed!
    queryset = models.LikeDislike.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LikeDislikeSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        # if you want pass post_id and user_id in url:
        post_user = get_object_or_404(LikeDislike, post_id=self.kwargs["post_id"], user_id=self.kwargs["user_id"]) 
        # if you want pass post_id and user_id in body of request:
        post_user = get_object_or_404(LikeDislike, post_id=self.request.data["post_id"], user_id=self.request.data["user_id"])
        return post_user

    def perform_create(self, LikeDislikeSerializer):
        LikeDislikeSerializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

now if you request to your url with PUT method the `LikeDislikeCreateUpdateDeleteView` view trying to update `post_user` (that came from `def get_object`) with `LikeDislikeSerializer` .and if you request to this url with DELETE method the view will delete object that is came from `def get_object` . hope help

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can – it's just a matter of overriding [`get_object()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/89ac0a1c7ef6153312890376ac142674b28b04f1/rest_framework/generics.py#L75) suitably in your views to retrieve the object to modify or delete using different parameters than the PK.